# Directory access control with Apache: do I need to use a specific .htaccess?

Tags: linux, apache, authentication, webserver

I have an Apache webserver, and in the Apache configuration, I have

```
Alias /backups "/backups"
<Directory "/backups">
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I can access files via `http://127.0.0.1/backups`. The problem is everyone can access that.

I have a web interface, e.g. `http://localhost/admin`m that is protected with htaccess and password.

Now I don't want separate `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` for `/backups`, and I don't want a second password prompt when a user clicks on `/backups` in the web interface. Is there any way to use same `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` for the backups directory?

Comment: i think it more of linux knowledge than web . At webmasters linux tag has only 27 questions .

Comment: @Mirror51: Linux is not relevant to your question. Since your users are accessing the files through a web interface, the access control is performed by Apache, not Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Anything you set in .htaccess you can set in the Apache configuration.

What you'll do is add the directives from your /admin .htaccess to your /backup directory context.